# Entity Framework multiple table with linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, code-first

for code first models:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
} 

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

I created entity framework model from code first. Its working fine. Now i want to query select for User table using linq.

```
public IEnumerable GetLicensee()
{
    using (var db = new DataModelContext())
    {
        IEnumerable query = (from b in db.User
                             select new { UserName= b.UserName,Address=b.Addresses }).ToList();

        return query;
    }
}
```

It's not returning address table, only returns username.

Comment: Are you sure the database table contains related addresses? Did you check the generated tables - there must be `User_Id` column in `Address` table.

Comment: yes, user_id is there. issue is fixed by using include("addresses")

Comment: There is no way the posted query to be fixed with `Include`. If it was fixed, than the query is different, and the post is misleading.

Comment: @IvanStoev you can propose solution here. i will try that too.

Comment: It's not about who will provide a solution. I assume once you are asking you have an issue, all I'm saying is that if the data is correct and EF model is correct, the issue cannot be the way you describe it. The `Include` will help if you are returning list of `User` objects, while with query like yours it's simply ignored, hence cannot "fix" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF by default turned on Lazy Loading, so  You need use eager loading by call `Include()`, this method also get releated Entities, in your case `Include("Addresses")` method get releated `Adressess`

> Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as part of the query. Eager loading is achieved by use of the Include method.

```
public IEnumerable GetLicensee()
{
        using (var db = new DataModelContext())
        {
        IEnumerable query = (from b in db.User.Include("Addresses")
                     select new { UserName= b.UserName,Address=b.Addresses }).ToList();

            return query;
        }
 }
```

Here find  [more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: OP is using **projection** query, so no eager or whatever loading is needed.

Comment: @IvanStoev if lazy loading is on

Comment: its giving error on (u=>u.addresses): Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: @Alex It doesn't matter.

Comment: @Sara Khan add `using System.Data.Entity `

Comment: @Wiśnicki what if i want to return only only specific field from address table. like address.Street ?

Comment: @M. Wiśnicki also there is another issue, i'm using GetLicensee() in web API when i'm calling it from front end it's not returning addresses there. i checked in debugger on API its fine but now issue is coming for front end only.